# How to create Row in dialog or alert dialog using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a row in a dialog or alert dialog box so I can add a form for first and last name in flutter.[image: here is an image of a first and last name in a row widget]

Answer (score 4):

For a column to form in an alert dialog box you have put the textfield in an expanded widget.

```
 Row(children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: TextField(),
                ),
               SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
               Expanded(
                   child: TextField(),
               ),
    ]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but this should work,all you have to do is style the widgets in the Row widget according to the image you put

```
 showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
 
      content: Container(
          child: Row(
             children:[
                 Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "First Name",
                        ),
                     ),
                  ),
                 Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Last Name",
                       ),
                     ),
                  ),
             ]
          ),
       ),
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: If there is any issue, feel free to comment

Comment: Zaza, yes there is an issue. It is throwing an error. I try adding a width and height to the container. However it is still not working.

Comment: I would like to see the error, sorry i currently can't test the code i gave to you

Comment: Zaza, I figured it out. You have to put the textfield in an expanded widget for it to work.

Comment: Alright, That's great, I'll edit my answer to contain that. Please upvote the answer, Thanks